# Can i extract Chinese text from PDF and convert into english language?

Tags: iphone

I have chinese ebook in PDF format in iphone. So i want to extract chinese words from PDF and convert into english, it is possible in iphone using objective-C

Thanks

Comment: google translate? bablefish?(if it still exists)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [Microsoft Translate API](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/dev/).

Comment: It is possible to use Google Translate API in iphone.

Comment: Yes, but the Google Translate API is being decommissioned.

Comment: i want simply parsing the PDF and extracting text then it convert using any language either C, C++, C#, objective-C.